# Executing script from shell problem

Tags: bash, python, lubuntu, scripts

Lubuntu Raring Ringtail. I want to be able to execute my scripts with `./`

I start my python script with `#!/usr/bin/python` and it says

```
bash : ./myscript.py: /usr/bin/python^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

If I use `#!/usr/bin/env python` it gives a similar error:

```
: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

I absolutely have python installed, and can run the scripts as normal with `python myscript.py`

Comment: Have you taken a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975011/pycharm-usr-bin-pythonm-bad-interpreter ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the `^M` you can see that the file myscript.py is using windows/dos-style line breaks (Windows uses CR LF (carriage return + line feed) at the end of a line. Unix only uses LF - so what you see as `^M` is the CR. So what you are not using `/usr/bin/python` but `/usr/bin/python<CR>` that does not exist.

You can remove the `^M` using `dos2unix` (do a `sudo apt-get install dos2unix` to install and then use `dos2unix myscript.py`).

Answer (score 3):

Do this, then try your Python script:

```
$ tr -d '\r' < test.py > newtest.py
```

This **removes the carriage returns created from Windows**

To further reading, [Remove Windows carriage returns with tr](http://wiredrevolution.com/system-administration/remove-windows-carriage-returns-with-tr)